# iOS real-time detect some marks from camera

Tags: swift, camera, ocr, detect, vision

I want to make a scanner for documents with special marks in the corners. So that when you turn on the camera, you search for marks on the document and automatically take a photo when they are found.
I looked at what **Vision** allows you to determine the text through the viewfinder, but not sure that it can do what I need. I found an example app in AppStore that does this.

https://itunes.apple.com/ru/app/whitelines/id552914549?l=en&mt=8

How can I implement this in my app? What frameworks to use?

Answer (score 0):

One very much popular and accurate is 'OpenCV' which needs to understand first. It will help to detect mark and you can take direct shot using its method. If your app is like using a good amount of image and video processing OpenCV will help you a lot.

But for this you will have to learn it.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize ARKit to do most of the work. Apple's [Detecting Images in an AR Experience](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/detecting_images_in_an_ar_experience) sample code shows how you provide ARKit an image of the special marks, and ARKit notifies you at runtime when it recognizes them in the camera feed.

Since the example uses SceneKit as the renderer, the notification it uses is `renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor)`. See the app's `ViewController.swift` file.

The sample app flashes the recognized image on the screen, but you can easily substitute that action with your code that takes a photo. You don't need to a capture a new photo, instead just access the current frame of the camera feed. That's stored in `sceneView.session.currentFrame!.capturedImage`.